# Calling an activity From another Package

Tags: android, view, android-activity

I have an activity in package com.qz.launchfoneclayactivity. I need to start an activity in a package com.qz.Test. I tried Setting the component and used SetClass also but of no help...Below is my manifest of com.qz.launchfoneclayactivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.qz.launchfoneclayactivity"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

         <activity android:name="com.x.test.StartUpActivity" />// This is the Activity name in another package
        <activity
            android:name="com.qz.launchfoneclayactivity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

below is my part of manifest of second package

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    package="com.qz.test" 
    android:versionCode="xx" 
    android:versionName="x.x.x">
    ......................


<activity android:name=".StartUpActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" 
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"                   
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >                        
            <intent-filter>                        
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />                        
            </intent-filter>                              
            </activity>
```

Comment: do you want to start your app with that activity or just start that activity from another activity ?

Comment: You show your code where you are trying to start this activity from another activity besides these xml files.

Answer (score 1):

try as to open android Application  Activity from your  Application :

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.qz.test",
                            "com.qz.test.StartUpActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i did this 
Intent oIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
  oIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.qz.test","com.qz.test.StartUpActivity"));

but when i debug after startActivity(ointent) im not getting the dubbger at the oncreate of StartUpActivity.

Comment: @user1340801 : because you have not added <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> in StartUpActivity Activity so try after adding this in StartUpActivity manifast file

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K : i even tried that as below ..
Intent oIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
oIntent.setComponent(newComponentName("com.qz.Foneclay","com.qz.Foneclay.StartUpActivity"));
with 
<activity android:name=".StartUpActivity"android:launchMode="singleTop"android:excludeFromRecents="true"android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">        
 <intent-filter>  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />                        
  </intent-filter>                              
            </activity>

Comment: Nope im not getting any error ....this activty is getting executed ..like consider the launching activity is a simple hello world..then im getting hello world in the phone screen but im not getting at the oncreate of the launched activity

Comment: @user1340801 : mean activity is starting but you are saying activity onCreate is not executing ?

Comment: no no..look the below is the activity which is launching an activity

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  Intent oIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
  oIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.qz.xxx","com.qz.xxx.StartUpActivity"));    
     oIntent.putExtra("type", "STOREFONEINFO");
     oIntent.putExtra("pid", "fone-3033-897276968");
     oIntent.putExtra("pidsource", "fonecenter");
     oIntent.putExtra("registrationID", 1233);
     oIntent.putExtra("deviceID", 1234);
     startActivity(oIntent);

now im not going inot the oncreate of StartUpActivity

Answer (score 0):

If packages belong to different applications, mark the activity with `android:exported` in manifest file. Then external packages can start it using an Intent with its full class name.

```
Intent start = new Intent(this,<target_class_name>);
startActivity(start);
```